I am getting error while capturing paymentIntent using stripe nodejs
pe: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
raw: {
code: 'payment_intent_unexpected_state',
doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/payment-intent-unexpected-state',
message: 'This PaymentIntent could not be captured because it has a status of requires_action. Only a PaymentIntent with one of the following statuses may be captured: requires_capture.',
// import stripe from 'stripe';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Console } from 'node:console';
import test from 'node:test';
import stripePackage, { Stripe } from 'stripe';
import { never } from 'zod';
const stripe = new stripePackage(process.env.STRIPE_KEY as string);

console.log('process.env.STRIPE_KEY', process.env.STRIPE_KEY);
// const stripeClient = new stripe(process.env.STRIPE_KEY as string, {
//   apiVersion: '2023-10-16',
// });

export const createIntentServices = async (data: any) => {
  try {
    // console.log(process.env.STRIPE_KEY ,"  ---",stripeClient)
    if (!data.amount) {
      throw new Error('Amount is missing');
    }
    // const token = await stripe.tokens.create({
      
    //   card: {
    //     number: '4242424242424242',
    //     exp_month: "12",
    //     exp_year: "2023",
    //     cvc: '123',
        
    //   },
      
    // });
    // console.log(token);
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create();
    const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
      { customer: customer.id },
      { apiVersion: '2023-10-16' }
    );
    
const token = await stripe.tokens.create({
  account: {
    individual: {
      first_name: 'Jane',
      last_name: 'Doe',
    },
    tos_shown_and_accepted: true,
  },
});
console.log("token",token)


    // if (!token.id) {
    //   throw new Error('Token not generated');
    // }

  
// const confirmationToken = await stripe.testHelpers.confirmationTokens.create({
//   payment_method: 'pm_card_visa',
// });
// console.log(confirmationToken);
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: data.amount,
      currency: process.env.CURRENCY || 'usd',
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      payment_method_options: {
        card: {
          capture_method: 'manual',
         
        },
      },
      
      capture_method:"manual",
      // use_stripe_sdk:true,
      customer: customer.id,
      payment_method:"pm_card_visa",
      confirm:true,
      description:"transaction for parking",
      
      
    });
  //   const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  //     amount: 2000,
  //     currency: 'usd',
  //     automatic_payment_methods: {
  //       allow_redirects:"never",
  //       enabled: true,
  //     },
  //     confirm:true,
  //     // return_url:"https://docs.stripe.com/payments/payment-methods/overview",
  //     payment_method:"pm_card_visa"
  //   });
  //  console.log("------",paymentIntent,"--------");
   
    if (!paymentIntent) {
      throw new Error('Something went wrong, Try again later');
    }

    const paymentConfirm = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(
      paymentIntent.id,
      
      {  payment_method: 'pm_card_visa' }
    );

    // const paymentConfirm = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(paymentIntent.id,  confirm);
    // console.log(paymentConfirm);
    if (paymentIntent.status === 'requires_action') {
    console.log("url------",paymentIntent.next_action?.redirect_to_url?.url);
      console.log('3DS authentication required.');
    }
    console.log(paymentIntent);
    if (!paymentConfirm) {
      throw new Error('Something went wrong, Try again later');
    }
       
    return {
      message: 'Payment Intent created successfully',
      status: 200,
      data: {
        paymentIntent,
        ephemeralKey,
        customer,
        paymentConfirm,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

export const capturePaymentServices = async (data: any) => {
  try {
    console.log(data);
    // const res=await stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve(data.paymentId);
    // console.log("-----",res);
    if (!data.paymentId) {
      throw new Error('PaymentId is missing');
    }
    
    const intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.capture(data.paymentId, {
      amount_to_capture: data.amount,
    });

    return {
      message: 'Payment captured successfully',
      status: 200,
      data: intent,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

export const cancelPaymentServices = async (data: any) => {
  try {
    if (!data.paymentId) {
      throw new Error('PaymentId is missing');
    }
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.cancel(data.paymentId);

    return {
      data: paymentIntent,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

how can i solve this error

Right now you are confirming server-side but your payment requires 3DS to be completed. The recommended route is that you confirm client-side, like shown in the canonical flow (docs) and this would handle 3DS automatically if it is required. If you do want to confirm server-side, then you would want to implement handling of 3DS as indicated at https://docs.stripe.com/payments/3d-secure/authentication-flow to complete the payment.
